# what's the main difference between script_fields and runtime_mapping, or how to make a choice?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 8.x. It seems they are having some similarities, and I can't find a very clear document of the main difference between them.
I'm aready found out field defined in script_fields can not be used in "sort" field.
How about other difference?

I want a document link about this question or some explanation.
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html#runtime-benefits) documentation for understanding main differance between script and runtime field.

Major difference is, Runtime field you can be able to use in  all type of query, aggregation and sort but Script fields can only fetch values.

Perfroamnce wise both are similar and there is no major change in performance.

If you want to do search relate operation like sort, query and aggregation on new field then go with runtime field and if you need just field in response then you can use script field.

Also, You can replace [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) with runtime field. You can see in below example that script is definded as runtime field and it is used in query and same can be used in sort or aggregation and not need to define script again.

```json
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "http.clientip": {
      "type": "ip",
      "script": """
        String clientip=grok('%{COMMONAPACHELOG}').extract(doc["message"].value)?.clientip;
        if (clientip != null) emit(clientip);
      """
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "http.clientip": "40.135.0.0"
    }
  },
  "fields" : ["http.clientip"]
}
```